# Amazon S3 list object in reverse order

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently when i call `$s3->list_objects()` method it return me objects in the order those objects were added. I want to list object in reverse order so that i can have newest objects first. I cannot find any parameter that i can pass to the `$s3->list_objects()` method that can reverse the order. I am using Amazon S3 PHP SDK. Is there is any such parameter or method?

Comment: Have you checked documentation?

Comment: indeed i checked the documentation. Than i came here on SO :(

Comment: Just to help anyone who comes here, AWS S3 will return objects in **Alphabetical Order**, not necessarily the order they were added. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html Look at the **marker** parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking to do the same thing and I really don't feel like I want a DB in the way to keep track of the latest objects. Since you just need them to have alphabetically reverse order keys.

A timestamp is alphabetical in ordering usually. A timestamp can be represented as a long. We can get a reverse alphabetical time identifier by taking the (max long - timestamp long) and formatting that with all leading 0s.

So if you store your S3 Objects with the key = prefix + timestampId + postfix you can use list to get the newest objects.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `list_objects()` is a `Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model` so you need to work with the methods offered by that class.  In order to do the paginated requests like mentioned in your comment below, you might need to do something like this:

```
$object_array = array();
$continue = true;
$list_params = array('Bucket' => 'your_aws_bucket', 'MaxKeys' => 1000);
while (true === $continue) {
    $result_obj = $s3->list_objects($list_params);
    $current_array = $result_obj->get('Contents');
    $object_array = array_merge($object_array, $current_array);
    $is_truncated = $result_obj->get('isTruncated');
    if ($is_truncated) {
        $list_params['Marker'] = $result_obj->get('NextKeyMarker');
    } else {
        $continue = false;
    }
}  
$reversed_array = array_reverse($object_array);
```

Note that if you are talking about 100,000 files, you might see that keeping the entire array for all files in memory becomes problematic, so you might want to rethink your need to have all in memory like you propose.

Comment: assume there are 100,000 files in a bucket. The array can return me only 10,000 keys in single request and than i can make it reverse. But this is not the issue, it will only revers those 10,000 keys. And when i will do the 2nd request for next 10,000 keys i have to reverse it again. but First 10,000 keys were not the latest if there are more than 10,000 keys in a bucket. I hope i explained the issue well?

Comment: @KhawerZeshan You should update the original question with this information, as this certainly makes a difference in your approach.  I have updated my answer to reflect this new use case.